# How do I make progress bar steps equal to a decimal number in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want the Progress bar steps be equal to a decimal like `3.2`.

```
progressBar1.Steps = 3.2;
```

I have tried the above code. However, it is not working.

Comment: It is an int value from 1 to 100 describing the completion ratio. Only whole integers make any difference

Comment: Like Shannon said you can only use integers. Also you need to use `.` as the fraction separator for `float` or `doubles`.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger, not necessary `100`. `Maximum` can be different. `3.2 ` is 32 in range [0, 1000]

Comment: Yeah, fine - you can SEND 3.2 to a progress bar, but it will only increment in steps of 1/100

Answer (score 4):

Increase the `Maximum` tenfold (so that it is 1000), and then increment it by 32 each time to get the desired functionality.

**1.** Set the `Maximum` property of the progress bar in the form designer to 1000.

**2.** Set the `Step` property of the progress bar in the form designer to 32.

Now, whenever your progress bar is incremented, you will get the same effect as if you were incrementing by 3.2

Comment: Include an example as well

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Because it makes the answer more complete.